# Line Height of Font

Tags: fonts, typography, font-design

I am designing my own font with Type 3.2.

I have exported the font as an .otf and it is working well.  However, for some reason the line height seems to work differently with my new font than the existing fonts.

With my new font, the cursor is towards the bottom - meaning that the top of some characters can be cut off.

[image: Here is my new font - see how the top of the F is cut off?]

When I take the same thing and change the font to Calibri, the cursor is much more centered.

[image: Here is Calibri]

How can I make it so that my font behaves better?

Comment: It seems like you did an error during the font crestion process. You need to put your letterd further to the baseline

Comment: Using FontForge, how would I be able to make this change for all of the glyphs at once?

Comment: @William: Select all glyphs, *transform, move.*

Comment: I think it has something to do with the descender height. http://i.stack.imgur.com/HusW0.png

Comment: I know in FontLab the character's height (if aligned correctly during the creation process) is calculated in the "font info" boxes (where you tell the app your font's name etc), could it be the same here?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't one value, but the UPM or em-size. The standard for OpenType fonts is for 1000 units, while in TrueType fonts, the UPM is by convention a power of two, generally set to 1024 or 2048. However the number you choose is up to you, and put simply, this value can be defined as the space that spans from the lowest-possible descender to highest possible ascender.

I say lowest and highest possible because while each glyph is different, the values must be the same for the whole font, and also across all styles in the family.  This is not to say that the outlines for any glyph will occupy this entire space, but rather these are the dimensions that all glyphs will fit into.

The descended looking cursor pictured in your post could also be caused by setting an underline height and width that extends below the descender.  Less likely, though still a possibility, is that your glyphs may not be sitting on the baseline.  I have never used "Type 3.2" but it is hard to imagine the latter could be the case without you being aware of it.

A similar concept which you should familiarise yourself with is how the x-height affects the size-variance between different fonts set at the same point size.  More on that:

http://www.thomasphinney.com/2011/03/point-size/

Comment: BTW, I only included that last bit regarding the x-height because of how you chose to title your question, which you might consider changing or clarifying as the problem you are describing is not the result of line-height.  Provided that the values you set you for your font's dimensions are correct and consistent, of course.